# Upload image after taken from android camera phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, cordova

I am working on an app where user can take a picture which then is uploaded to server, for some reason it stops after the function uploadPhoto() is fired. They take a picture with their phone, which they can see, and When they click the submit button it fires the function uploadPhoto() which should upload it to a php page. I believe It has something to do with the UploadPhoto() function having an error. Server is configured properly it worked with other test.

```
       var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }
    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
      // Get image handle
      console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = imageData;
    }
    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
      // console.log(imageURI);
      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';
      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }
    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoWithData() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
    }
    function capturePhotoWithFile() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }
    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
/* function getImage() {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('get picture failed');
 }, {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
}
*/
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 $('.whathapp').text(options.fileName);
    console.log(options.fileName);
 var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "https://link.com/upload.php", function(result){
$('.whathapp').text('worked');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
 }, function(error){
     $('.whathapp').text('failed');
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }, options);
 }
```

Comment: The js here seems okay. But do the text "worked" comes up or not? If it does, the problem (much probably) is in your backend in the php code. More, check error logs in the developer console of your browser. Maybe there is a conflict with another library or something other.

Comment: the text does not popup, I dont feel It is in the backend because I tested it with a version that uploads from the gallery and it worked. I am using phonegap on phone view and they do not have the developer console mode for easy debug. Can't run in chrome because it needs the androids cam, I will keep trying

Comment: Okay so if it doesn't pop up means that the problem is in the front end. Please, could you give a try using "try" and "catch" and print the result of the exception in a class or ID, so you can see it.

Comment: Hey @Optiroot I get "CANNOT CALL METHOD 'LASTINDEXOF' OF UNDEFINED'

Comment: I don't know very well Phonegap, so I don't know if "imageURI" is a definited var from Phonegap or not. But if that is not the case, it means that IMAGEURI is not defined and doesn't exist. More, I can't find where you define it (in fact I see it is called in another function too)
From where it comes from?

Comment: Hey @Optiroot I think that may be the root of the cause, I tried to define it as imageData, no luck yet, there is an option to do string data as an image too I may be able to use

Comment: @Optiroot Just got it to work when i put uploadPhoto function in the Capture photo function like so "navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType:" now I just need to figure out how to make it only submit with button, I think im closer though, thanks for the try catch tip!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156717/discussion-between-optiroot-and-jeff).